# Repeating background gradient in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, gradient

In [this pen](http://codepen.io/vahidseo/pen/uowfg), the position of the **repeating background gradient** is animated. This makes **Google Chrome** render the **background gradient** wrong. It works fine in **Mozilla Firefox**.

How can I fix it?

For my body background gradient I used this:

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(40deg, #d61e29 0px, #661011 40px);
```

and the animation is bg:

```
animation: bg 15s infinite linear;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's related to this bug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162538. If you remove your setting the background size to 200% you see the gradient clears up somewhat. If you reduce it to 50% it becomes smooth. I think you're going to have to take another approach to the animated background. Also notice setting the angle to 0 gives smooth gradient.

Try giving a fixed background size, in effect tiling it, so that the tiles seem nicely. background-size: 100px 100px; not sure the exact size to get the seems right. Here is a code pen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vuFod;

```
background-size: 100px 100px
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #d61e29 0px, #661011 71px);
```